# How to close the select in file write?

Tags: perl

I write the output in the file by using `select`.

```
open my $handler, ">","newfile.txt";
select ($handler);
print "Something print into the file";
print "Something print into the file";
print "Something print into the file";

close $handler;  #This is not working

print "print into the terminal";
```

For this easily i will do using without `select`,

```
open my $handler, ">","newfile.txt";
print $handler " print on file";
print "print on terminal";
```

Using `select` how can i do it?
How to close the `select`? Also i want to print the output on the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to first set the default filehandle back to what it had been

```
my $old_fh = select($handle);    
# your prints ...
select $old_fh;
close $handle;
```

The `select` sets up the new default filehandle if supplied an expression, returning the current one.  So the way you have it you are trying to close the default filehandle.

From `perldoc -f select`

> select FILEHANDLE
>   
>   select 
>   
>   Returns the currently selected filehandle. If FILEHANDLE is
>   supplied, sets the new current default filehandle for output. This
>   has two effects: first, a "write" or a "print" without a
>   filehandle default to this FILEHANDLE. Second, references to
>   variables related to output will refer to this output channel.